# Creating a two-level Treemap in Highcharter R with data_to_hierarchical

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm attempting to create a two-level Treemap in R using `data_to_hierarchical()` from the `highcharter` package. It needs to have two levels - the topmost being the `Level1` variable, which can then be clicked to view the second `Level2` variable:

[image: Picture of a single level treemap with random variables]

How can I make it two-level? I've done a lot of googling, but there's a lot of conflicting information and depreciated functions regarding making highcharts treemaps in R, and I haven't been able to find an answer.

Reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)


set.seed(110)

ex <- data.frame(
  Level1 = rep(paste0("Country", seq(1:5)), each = 5),
  Level2 = rep(paste0("Sector", seq(1:5)), 5),
  Percentage = runif(25, 0, 1)
)

ex %>% 
  data_to_hierarchical(c(Level1, Level2), Percentage) %>%
  hchart(type = "treemap")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the `allowTraversingTree`, `levelIsConstant`, and `levels` arguments to my `hchart()` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)


set.seed(110)

ex <- data.frame(
  Level1 = rep(paste0("Country", seq(1:5)), each = 5),
  Level2 = rep(paste0("Sector", seq(1:5)), 5),
  Percentage = runif(25, 0, 1)
)

ex %>% 
  data_to_hierarchical(c(Level1, Level2), Percentage) %>%
  hchart(type = "treemap",
         allowTraversingTree = T,
         levelIsConstant = F,
         levels = list(
           list(level = 1, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, 
                                             format = "{point.name}<br>
                                                      {point.value}%"), borderColor = "black", borderWidth = 2),
           list(level = 2, dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE))
         )
         )
```

Top level:

[image: Picture of top level of treemap, showing fictional countries]

Second level:

[image: Picture of second level of treemap, showing fictional sectors]